Dynamic resolution video, resolution won't be adjusted correctly after re-encode
I am recoding the live stream; many of them will adjust resolution because of PK.
For example, the resolution is 720x1280 when solo; after starting PK, the resolution becomes 900x720; after PK ends and go back to solo, the resolution becomes 720x1280 again.
These recorded video files are too big, and they are all h264, so I am trying to re-encode them to AV1 to reduce file size.
But after re-encoding, the resolution are fixed and won't be adjusted correctly like before.
Here's image, I don't have enough reputation to post images.
https://i.sstatic.net/LhLAXMjd.gif
For example, the original file is on the left side, and the re-encoded file is on the right side.
This video starts at 900x720, PK ends and back to solo at 00:00:06, resolution changes to 720x1280.
ffplay plays the original video file, everything seems good.
ffplay plays the re-encoded video file, after 00:00:06, the resolution still keeps 900x720 and causes graphics to stretch and cut off.
Here's the command I used:
ffmpeg -i original.flv -y -c:v libsvtav1 re-encode.mp4

I tried to re-encode using the same codec, h264, but the same problem still
ffmpeg -i original.flv -y -c:v libx264 re-encode.mp4

Have no idea how to fix this
Here's video file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/0vaxtzurwhom8bn/ReEncode_Resolution.zip/file
I expect re-encoded video file can be plays correctly in ffplay (resolution change when it needs to)

The issue is that FFmpeg reads the resolution of the first frame, and scale (resize) the remaining video to the resolution of the first frame.
We may solve it by scaling and padding the entire video to (say) 900x720 resolution:
ffmpeg -y -i original.flv -vf "scale='if(lt(iw/ih,900/720),-2,900)':'if(lt(iw/ih,900/720),720,-2)',pad=900:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1" -c:v libx264 re-encode.mp4



if(lt(iw/ih,900/720),-2,900) - sets the width to 900 if frame is too wide (otherwise set to -2 for keeping the aspect).
if(lt(iw/ih,900/720),720,-2) - sets the height to 720 if the frame is too high (otherwise set to -2 for keeping the aspect).
pad=900:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 - Add black margins (if required) for fixing the resolution to 900x720.

Note: -2 applies automatic ratio, but even.

Edit:
Re-encoding a file with multiple resolutions:
Re-encoding a single file with multiple resolutions in a "single pass" using FFmpeg is not supported (as far as I know).
We may split the file into multiple files (segments), re-encode each segment, and concatenate the encoded segments.
Automating the process, requires a script (which isn't included).
The following solution shows the stages ("manually") with the sample input video:

Split the video into segments - each segment contains a single GOP (starting with a keyframe, without any keyframe in the middle).
Using Segment Muxer with -segment_time 0 suppose to do that:
 ffmpeg -i original.flv -c copy -f segment -segment_time 0 -segment_list list.txt -segment_list_type ffconcat %05d.flv


Encode each segment with AV1 encoder:
 ffmpeg -y -i 00000.flv -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 32 00000.mp4
 ffmpeg -y -i 00001.flv -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 32 00001.mp4
 ffmpeg -y -i 00002.flv -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 32 00002.mp4
 ffmpeg -y -i 00003.flv -c:v libaom-av1 -crf 32 00003.mp4


Edit the generated list.txt - replace .flv with .mp4 for all files:
 ffconcat version 1.0
 file 00000.mp4
 file 00001.mp4
 file 00002.mp4
 file 00003.mp4


Concatenate the MP4 segments files using Concat Demuxer:
 ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4




Making sure that output.mp4 contains multiple resolutions (using FFprobe):
ffprobe -i output.mp4 -show_frames -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,width,height -of csv

The output is:
frame,900,720
frame,900,720
...
frame,900,720
frame,900,720
frame,720,1280
frame,720,1280
...
frame,720,1280
frame,720,1280
...


This method seems to lower the graphics quality.
original.flv, resolution is 900x720 at first, then it changes to 720x1280, so it has more pixels to present.
But if using this command, resolution will be fixed at 900x720, when the PK ends, it will be padded with black pixels, so the actual valid resolution will be 405x720, this is much lower than 720x1280.
Is it possible to change the output video's resolution dynamically? Just like the original.flv

You have to identify the maximum resolution in the stream and scale to that.

How to identify the maximum resolution? Should it be 900x1280? This is bigger than both resolutions, so it can keep original graphics quality, but it's likely to use more disk space because the resolutions are bigger. My purpose is to reduce file size, so I don't think it's the best solution.

Even if this finally works, it still have many padded black pixels in the output video, included padded black pixels is not good for play the video in different aspect ratio devices(PC, phone). In the best case, padded black pixels should be generated by player, but not included in video file itself. original.flv doesn't have these padded black pixels at all, every pixel is useful, it change resolution when it needs to, that's what I want.

I just want the re-encoded file to have the same dynamic resolution compared to the original file and no padded black pixels.

I don't know if it's possible without programming (using command line).

@taylorelvin107 I updated my answer - showing how to re-encode a file with multiple resolutions. You are probably not going to be very happy with that solution, because it shows a manual solution (without a script). Implementing a Python script is relatively simple - you may ask in Stack Overflow (give reference to this post). Note that in case you don't know any Python it might be problematic, because SO questions are expected to include what you have tried.

Many thanks! This is exactly what I am looking for. I still have some questions though. 1. How to convert these flv segments to mp4 segments in one line command? That original.flv is a cut file actually, the original video file's duration is 06:36:37, which produces 7934 flv segments. I believe running ffmpeg 7934 times will be slower than running it only 1 time. 2. This split and concat procedure, is it accurate enough? I mean, is it possible lost some video frames or audio frames in the final output video?

Is it better to only cut the video file when the resolution changed? Here's the command I used to re-encode, the purpose is to reduce file size and keep it visually lossless. ffmpeg -i 000000174.flv -y -c:a libopus -b:a 96K -c:v libsvtav1 -preset 6 -crf 31 -keyint_min 300 -g 300 -svtav1-params "fast-decode=1:tune=0:enable-tf=0:enable-qm=1:qm-min=0" -pix_fmt yuv420p10le 000000174.mp4

I expect the best compression ratio. I heard somewhere that the encoder will look forward and afterward to find the best solution, so the more duration, the better the encoder works. But these 7934 segments are all only 2 seconds in duration, so it's not good for compression. I am a newbie, please correct me if I am wrong.

It could negligible. Preform a simple test with a file that has only one resolution. In case it's not. Concat all the parts with the same resolution to single file before re-encoding (the script is going to be more complicated)

This split and concat procedure works for the sample original.flv, but when I try exactly the same thing on the full-length 6-hour video, it shows many Non-monotonic DTS; previous: 288259217, current: 240819492; changing to 288259218. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file when running ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4.

This causes ffplay to not be able to seek from 02:40:00 to 05:08:00, it will always seek to frame 9600 when trying to seek to this range. This warning doesn't show when re-encode  segments, it only appears when concat. I used this command to re-encode since libaom-av1 is too slow, ffmpeg -i 00003.flv -y -c:v libsvtav1 -preset 12 -crf 63 00003.mp4.

I tried to use this command to re-encode full-length video, and no seek problem appeared, so I have no idea again. Here's the full-length video: https://www.mediafire.com/file/j7u27c2hfrtkisk/original_full.rar/file

It's a bug in FFmpeg that related to concatenating MP4 files without re-encoding. try latest version of FFmpeg (version 7.1). Try replacing .mp4 with .mkv. I was thinking about the solution. The segment muxer accepts a list of segment split time (or frames) points. We may use FFprobe for getting the points where the resolution changes, and split to segments only in that points (getting much less segments). Example: ffprobe -skip_frame nokey -i original_full.flv -show_frames -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pts_time,width,height -of csv

After switching to .mkv, no seek problem anymore. But the duration is changed, original_full.flv duration is 06:36:37, and concat .mkv duration is 06:54:00. I tried ffmpeg -i original_full.flv -y -c:v libsvtav1 -preset 12 -crf 63 output_direct.mkv, and the duration is still 06:36:37. Is there something wrong when concat? Didn't see any warning through.

I wrote a python script to get the resolution-changed frames. How can I split video base on these? https://pastebin.com/8WxgGhcg
Got 2 more questions. 1. Why is this frame number not an integer but something like 23405.736000? 2. The frame interval is 3 instead of 1, the first frame is 0.136000, and the next frame is 3.125000. Is it possible the resolution changed at 2.000000 and lead to inaccurate cutting?

These are timestamps and not frame numbers. Your original video doesn't have 'coded_picture_number', and we have to use timestamps. Using FFprobe, I saw that original_full.flv is not fixed 30fps, but has some variable framerate (difficult to handle) - explains the duration issues (I suspect the after all the work there might be audio-video synchronization issues). For cutting by list of timestamps, read the documentation of segment muxer. Executing ffmpeg -h muxer=segment. shows -segment_times     <string>     E.......... set segment split time points. The list is comma separated.

Lucky there isn't audio-video synchronization issues. But it seems every segment is a little bit longer. The original video is 23797 seconds. In the previous test, 7935 segments were generated, and the total duration is 24853 seconds (I check every segment's duration and sum them up, so it's not related to concat).

If split with segment_times, ffmpeg -i original_full.flv -y -c copy -f segment -segment_times 771.125000,3314.265000,3573.294000,4214.695000,4227.896000,4258.329000,4689.595000,5226.398000,5970.857000,7709.785000,7994.456000,9208.486000,9469.333000,10848.889000,11945.691000,15243.758000,15656.554000,16399.655000,18666.942000,18961.573000,19015.277000 -segment_list list.txt -segment_list_type ffconcat %05d.flv

Then it will be 22 segments, and the total duration is 23800 seconds. So 7935 segments extend 1056 seconds, and 22 segments extend 3 seconds. 1056/7935=0.133, 3/22=0.136. It looks like every segment extends around 0.13 seconds.

I tried this procedure on another file, and then it failed to split at the correct time.https://www.mediafire.com/file/esawjkv05hpe9qg/sample2.rar/file
ffprobe -skip_frame nokey -i sample2.ts -show_frames -select_streams v -show_entries frame=pts_time,width,height -of csv
Run this command, and it shows many Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 621657000), but I don't see any problem playing this video in ffplay or PotPlayer.

Anyway, I run ffmpeg -i sample2.ts -y -c copy -f segment -segment_times 7271.704989,7481.593989,8577.330989,8631.877989,9723.348989,9934.060989 -segment_list list.txt -segment_list_type ffconcat %05d.ts and try to split it, then it generates only 1 segment with multi-resolution. I notice first frame's timestamp is 6310.744989, Is this the problem?
